# alphabetical collection of store in Choose Store View: dropdown on magento admin side

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

[image]I am using magento 1.9 . I need to show website ,store, and  storeview  collection by their name ascending order for Choose Store View: drop down on magento admin side dashboard.

Comment: I think you have better option. Use the sort order functionality to sort those stores like you want.

Comment: I think they are already sorted in Ascending order as per website names